# Avoid typing "python" in a terminal to open a .py script?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

Whilst running python scripts from my linux terminal, I find myself typing in `python myfile.py` way too much. Is there a way on linux (or windows) to execute a python script by just entering in the name of the script, as is possible with bash/sh? like `./script.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the script, put

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or whatever the path to Python is on your computer (the result of `which python` on Linux). This tells the system to run your script using `python`. You'll also need to do `chmod +x script.py` for it to work.

Or if you're really lazy, use `alias p=python` or something.

Comment: In Python, is often a better practice to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` to enable running using a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to `chmod 0755 script.py` and as a first line in script have something like

`#!/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your Python script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Depending on your version, and if `Python 3` is your default or not.

---

Then, set executable bits at the shell (maybe with `sudo` if needed):

```
chmod +x my_script_name.py
```

Note that with the above done, you could rename your Python script

```
mv my_script_name.py my_script_name
```

and then execute your Python script just by:

```
my_script_name
```

at the shell line.